¿Cómo se conjuga el verbo "abaldonar"?
En el DLE, en la inmensa mayoría de los verbos, si no en todos, además de la definción, se detalla la conjugación correspondiente y/o modelo de conjugación. Vease, por ejemplo, el caso de copiar.
Sin embargo, en el caso de abaldonar no ocurre lo mismo: apenas se recoge la etimología y las acepciones, pero no la conjugación, ni se indica si es regular o irregular, o qué modelo de conjugación sigue.
¿Hay alguna razón conocida para esa anomalía? ¿Un simple despiste de la RAE?
Como indica Danielillo en su comentario, existen otras páginas en internet donde sí figura una conjugación, pero siempre está la duda de la fiabilidad de esas páginas.

Una simple búsqueda en Google da la solución: conjugación verbo abaldonar

En este sitio se responden cuestiones acerca del idioma español, no sobre las políticas de contenido de otros sitios. Deberías elevar la consulta donde corresponda.

Los verbos en español que terminan en "-ar" son regulares y se conjugan eliminando la terminación "-ar" y agregando la terminación adecuada según la persona y el tiempo. Por ejemplo, en el tiempo presente se agrega "-o", "-as", "-a", "-amos", "-áis" o "-an" a la raíz restante.  Google AI

Atención con estas "nuevas cuentas"

En la versión del DLE de 2001, en la entrada abaldonar aparece la definición:

y un enlace hacia su conjugación que la muestra:

Tenemos pues, una información fiable de la conjugación.  Es curioso es que en la actual edición del DLE ya no figure esta.

No es tan sorprendente, ya que este verbo solo se encuentra en aragonés y no forma parte de la lengua común.
